# Nooby Java programmer confused at output (Constructors)

Tags: java, input, compiler-construction, io, case

I am a fairly new Java programmer and I am currently following an online tutorial to improve my skills. I found the following code example on the tutorial which all looks like it should run however I am getting a number of errors when I run the code in Eclipse.

This is my first program using cases however I am pretty sure I have the correct syntax maybe somebody can point out my error? Also I was surprised that the compiler complains about the line "System.out.println ("Are you sure (y - yes, n - no)?");"

I am getting errors on lines 3,4,7,8,10,11,15. Please can somebody tell me why my program will not run?

```
class Certainty  
{
    System.out.println ("Are you sure (y - yes, n - no)?");
    int ch = System.in.read ();
    switch (ch)
    {
       case 'Y':
       case 'y': System.out.println ("I am sure.");
                break;
       case 'N':
       case 'n': System.out.println ("I am not sure.");
                 break;
       Default : System.out.println ("Incorrect choice.");
    }
}
```

/* Thank you for all of the helpful responses I'm slowly starting to get my head around Java and I'm really enjoying it and loving how quickly my question was answered you guys are awsome.**/

Comment: where is ur main method?

Comment: you don't have any method in your class

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure you need to cast the ch to a char before you can use the switch: switch ((char)ch)

Comment: You can Declare the variables inside a class body.
But the statements should be a part of some method body to work good for you

Comment: @rhobincu No. That's not necessary.

Comment: Default should be with a lowercase D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This is my first program using cases however I am pretty sure I have the correct syntax maybe somebody can point out my error?

Most of the actual syntax around cases is correct, except that it's `default:` not `Default:` (capitalization matters).

But your class has step-by-step code immediately inside the class. You can't do that. It has to be inside initializers or (more commonly) constructors and/or methods.

Separately, `System.in.read()` may throw an `IOException`, which you have to either declare that your method throws or catch. In the example below, I catch it and just say it happened. Normally you'd do something more useful than that, but it's fine for this kind of quick test.

```
import java.io.IOException;  // <=== Tell the compiler we're going to use this class below
class Certainty  
{
    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        try {                      // `try` starts a block of code we'll handle (some) exceptions for
            System.out.println ("Are you sure (y - yes, n - no)?");
            int ch = System.in.read ();
            switch (ch)
            {
               case 'Y':
               case 'y': System.out.println ("I am sure.");
                        break;
               case 'N':
               case 'n': System.out.println ("I am not sure.");
                         break;
               default : System.out.println ("Incorrect choice.");
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {    // <== `catch` says what exceptions we'll handle
            System.out.println("An exception occurred.");
        }
    }
}
```

There, I've moved your code into the standard `main` method used with command-line Java apps, and fixed the `Default` thing.

Comment: +1 Although it needs a `throws IOException` or similar to compile.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my code and explaining it. @T.J Crowder You sir are a gentleman and a scholar.

Answer (score 1):

You should put these lines inside `main` method or any other method.
eg:

```
class Certainty  
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
    System.out.println ("Are you sure (y - yes, n - no)?");
        try
        { 
        int ch = System.in.read ();
        switch (ch)
        {
           case 'Y':
           case 'y': System.out.println ("I am sure.");
                    break;
           case 'N':
           case 'n': System.out.println ("I am not sure.");
                     break;
           default : System.out.println ("Incorrect choice.");
        }
       }//try
      catch (IOException e)
      {
        System.out.println("Error reading from user");
      }//catch

    }//end of main
 }
```

Comment: Immediately inside `class { ... }` do come declarations of fields and methods.

Comment: @JoopEggen What if we don't have any instance variables and methods other than main method in class?

Comment: expressed myself unclear; I wanted to add to your answer the explanation; that immediateöy inside the class body does not come code, but declarations of fields and methods (and constructory, initializers, inner classes).